# Emacs: How do I reverse `load-path`?

Tags: emacs, elisp, load-path, icicles

The question arises with connection to the problem of adding child dirs to the load-path. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/702280/788700) a solution. Unfortunately - it seems to revert the load-path. I tried to fix it myself, but can't do and need help.

So my question is: how do I revert a `load-path`.

I tried `(setq load-path (reverse load-path))` but it fails - which suggests that `load-path` is not a list...

**Edit**:

Reversing load path works, indeed - I don't know what I did wrong when I tried it before posting.

I'm facing a very strange problem `simple.el` shadows `sunrise-commander.el` - while it supposed to load before that. I thought - the problem is in the order in which I have dirs in a load path - but now - when I reversed the `load-path` - `progmodes` dir is before the `sunrise` one - the problem is still around. I'm puzzled.

I'll reformulate my question then: how do I make sure that a given extension is loading *after* the core Emacs's code?

**Edit 2**:

In case shadow doesn't mean, what I think - my actual problem is that many `sunrise-commander` and `icicles` keys are binded to core emacs functions. For example when I use icicles `M-p` is binded to

```
M-p runs the command recenter-top-bottom, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `window.el'.
```

While it should be `previous-history-element`. Similarly, when I use `sunrise-commander` `M-u` is binded to

```
M-u runs the command subword-backward, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `subword.el'.
```

while it realy should be `sr-history-next`.

**Edit 3**:

Oh I solved it! In the old days I used to install emacs things system-wide, thru synaptic package manager. Then I came with a resolution - that this way it is impossible to have my customizations with me. And after that I maintain a local emacs and emacs packages. So all I has to do is to remove all the system-wide emacs stuff.

** Edit 4**:

Nope it is not that. It way ErgoEmacs keybindings extension. After I commented it out I have `M-n` and `M-p` working fine in `icicles`. Though `RET` in Sunrise commander still calls dired function - not the sunrise one. Hopefully will solve it later.

Comment: Is there a typo between `revert` and `reverse` in this question? Otherwise, can you illustrate the issue. I don't get it.

Comment: there's a closing parenthesis missing in your post, is it a typo or maybe the explanation of your problem? Otherwise, `load-path` is a list and your expression should work (it does work for me). Maybe you could post more context: error message, current value of `load-path` (which you can obtain using `C-h v load-path`

Comment: As an aside, `nreverse` is worth knowing.

Comment: I don't think shadow means what you seem to think it means.  What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions are loaded by either `require` or `load`. The `load-path` simply specifies a list of folders in which `require` will search. Imagine you have the `.emacs.d/vendor` dir full of Emacs extensions and it's added to your `load-path` (the order of entries in the load path doesn't matter unless the same extension is in several of the folders there - something known as load-path shadowing, that can be examined with `M-x list-load-path-shadows`). You can do one of two things at this point:

```
(require 'extension)
;; or
(load "~/emacs.d/vendor/extension.el)
```

`require` has the added benefit, that it wouldn't load a library twice. So, to answer you question - to make sure that an extensions is loaded after the *core* (very few things are loaded automatically by Emacs) it just has to be required or loaded after the stuff you want it loaded after.

After you second edit I think you should take a look at [this great article on keybindings in Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/).

Comment: +1 different modes have different key bindings, the M-u binding should only happen in a Sunrise buffer (or, more painfully, a buffer whose major mode uses the Sunrise keymap).

Comment: Sunrise's buttons don't work for me in Sunrise. Not in text mode. Similarly In icicles - when I'm in minibuffer - M-n calls keyboard quit - which is seen in *messages*... I started all these load-path business out of hysteria. Actually I always thought that the placement of dirs in load-path doesn't matter. Thanks for reply anyway. Sunrise and Icicles got shadowed - even if I place the corresponding lines at the very end of my .emacs

Comment: You should probably trim down your `.emacs` to only sunrise and icicles config to pinpoint the exact problem - frankly I don't understand the problems. It seems quite unlikely that a major or a minor mode would bind something to M-p or M-u and it would be some regular Emacs command instead of something from the mode...

Comment: Please - see Edit 3 of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it matters, but regarding "how do I load something before simple.el": you can't because simple.el is preloaded in the `emacs' executable, so it's loaded long before the .emacs is loaded.